# How to find PhpNamespaceReferenceImpl in Zend FrameWork?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I want to modify the validation related email address in Zend Framework. But I'm confused with how to find the page related to validation in this. Actually it was already written and I need to modify its rule.

I tried to search all the pages in the project to find where this validation is defined and the PHP namespace is referenced to this – I’m at my wits’ end!”
Only thing that I could found is below commands.

```
1,use Zend\Validator;
2,$userEmailInput->getValidatorChain()->addValidator(new Validator\EmailAddress());
```

Could anyone please help me to find this treasure where it is located normally. Give some hints for finding this and for modifying the rules.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The file is located in folder `vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php`, as stated by the namespace.. You can even find it on [github](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/EmailAddress.php)

However, I discourage you to modify that specific file. On the first update, all your edits will be wiped out.

The right solution would be to create a new custom validator:

```php
namespace YourNamespace\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress;

class YourEmailAddress extends EmailAddress
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // Your validation logic..
    }
}
```

Then, where you need it:

```php
$userEmailInput->getValidatorChain()->addValidator(new YourNamespace\Validator\YourEmailAddress());
```

Comment: Where should I put this new validation file. Can you specify the path?

Comment: Anywhere you want inside your module, as long as you respect namespace. With the namespace in the example, the validator must be located in `module/yourmodule/src/Validator`